# CSS: Setting a background gradient to width 100% fine unless page scrolls

Tags: html, css

Here's two screen shots, showing the effect with a small viewport that has to be scrolled.

[image]
[image]

HTML looks like this: (ignoring head and html tags)

```
<body>
 <div id="grad1"></div>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <header>
  <h1 class="logo"><a href="/">Business Name</a></h1>
 </header> 
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a class="first" id="index" href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a  id="whatwedo" href="/whatwedo.php">What we do</a></li>
   <li><a  id="communicating" href="/communicating.php">Communicating</a></li>
   <li><a class="last" id="contact" href="/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 <section>
  <?= $content ?>
 </section>
 <footer>
  &copy; 2010
 </footer>
 </div> 
</body>
```

And the (trimmed down) CSS relating to body, grad1 and wrapper look like this:

```
body {
 color: #111;
 background-color: #3E9C9D;
}

#grad1 {
 height: 600px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -100;
 width: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#3E9C9D));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #3E9C9D 100%);
}


#wrapper {
 max-width:960px;
 min-width:840px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

How do I fix this? I have to have the gradient on a different div as far as I know, because I need to specify the height.

(I am aware that the CSS gradient doesn't work in IE - there is a background-image there to emulate the behaviour. It has the same problem.)

Comment: It is very bad idea to create browser-specific web pages. You should stick to the standards.

Comment: Firstly, I asked this 2 years ago, when this syntax was brand new, hence the lack of vendors. Secondly, it is standard: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-images/#linear-gradients . Thirdly, for older browsers I use this technique I developed: http://www.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/2010/dynamically-drawing-gradients-with-php/ to generate a png instead. Using this technique reduces loading time significantly, and works in all browsers once IE10 is out.

Comment: 1. -webkit- and -moz- are not standard and they will never be. You should not have used them 2 years ago, just like you should not use any new browser specific features the vendors may develop. 2. The CSS3 implementation has nothing to do with solutions given here. 3. Using non-standard gradients does NOT reduce loading time. You fail to understand that a narrow gradient image is very small. 4. Even when IE10 is out, the new technigue is NOT supported by all browsers. It is not suppoirted by old browsers most people are using. And for example on Windows XP, IE8 is the newest that can be used.

Comment: Using CSS gradients replaces an HTTP request and a 207 byte PNG with around 74 bytes of gzipped CSS. I know it's not much, but it's around half the download size. The rendering time is about equal for both techniques. Of course, this site doesn't have many gradients, but for other sites I've done the difference has been more significant. As I said, I'm using a PNG in old browsers, so this works everywhere, either by the PNG or by the CSS. The code above is only a snippet. Most people are not using old browsers.

Comment: Using the analytics package I've produced, in the last month 65% around 50,000 users across all my client's sites had browsers that can use CSS gradients. In a year, if the currrent trend stays the same, that should be around 3/4 of all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, for people who find this and can't work it out, the CSS should look like this:

```
body {
 color: #111;
 background-color: #3E9C9D;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#3E9C9D));
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff 0%, #3E9C9D 100%);
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-size: 100% 600px;
 -o-background-size: 100% 600px;
 -moz-background-size: 100% 600px;
 -webkit-background-size: 100% 600px;
}

#wrapper {
 max-width:960px;
 min-width:840px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Edit from 2 years after - the gradient syntax has changed somewhat, and now everyone supports it. Make sure you read up on the changes before using this code.

Comment: Thank you. The background-size works on Firefox but when tried on Chrome it does not. So am guessing Firefox is more compatible in this part. Am trying it with the specific browser switches.

Comment: Am using Chrome 14 and it does not work without using the -webkit option. If I use the background-size alone it works on Firefox but not on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behaviour for `position: absolute`, its coordinates are relative to the *viewport* at the time of rendering.

There probably exists a workaround for this that preserves the `grad1` DIV, but why not  simply put the background image/gradient into the body? From what I can see, the background is to expands across the whole document anyway.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I didn't do that because I have to specify a height for the element with the gradient (Otherwise the drawn gradient has a different height depending on each page)...

Comment: @Rich I see. From what I can see looking in the gradient documentation, you should be able to set a `background-size` to fix the height of the gradient (I haven't worked with gradients before but it looks like it.)

Comment: Yeah, I've just been digging around and found the same thing. It does work, but the gradient repeats. Setting no-repeat on the background image causes it to stop being rendered, setting repeat-y does nothing! :(

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

.gradient {
background: linear-gradient(top, #243d6e 0%,#031b4d 61%,#011132 100%); /* W3C */
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

attach .gradient to body tag or a container div.

Answer (score -1):

It is not good idea to create browser-specific web pages.

Gradient background that works on all browsers can be made simply by using a background image.

1. Create a narrow (even one pixel wide) image with gradient.
2. In CSS, set the background image repeat in x direction but not in y direction
3. Set the body background color to be the same as the color at the bottom of the image.

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
 color: #111;
 background-color: #3E9C9D;
 background-image: URL(gradient_green.png);
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#wrapper {
 max-width:960px;
 min-width:840px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```